# Calculation of magnetic force magnitude from a parmenant magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, experimental-physics, magnetic-fields

I was wondering how strong a magnet should be in order to be able to horizontally attract 0.2 Kg of pure iron at a distance of 0.3 M. Since I know nothing about magnets, I started looking for companies that provide magnets, and what different ones they offer, and I decided to pick a bar magnet. My problem here is that I couldn't relate the formulas I found online to calculate the strength of the required magnet to the properties given on magnet providers website.

The formula I found was: (is it true in the first place?)

$F= \mu m_1m_2/4\pi r^2 $

"$m_1$ and $m_2$ are the magnitudes of magnetic poles"
How do I relate $m_1$ and $m_2$ to the information that magnets providers give? 
The information that was on the providers website were: about Magnetic Face area, Thickness, Grade, Performance, vertical pull and slide resistance!

Lets assume normal air separation for the $\mu$.

Comment: The force required will depend not only on the mass of the object to be attracted, but on any forces holding it back (i.e. friction). To attract a block across a frictionless surface would require an infinitesimally small amount of force...

Comment: @Kyle Yes, let's assume a frictionless surface. But I am trying to calculate this in numbers, is the above formula correct?  I am not quite sure how to get this case into numbers :)

Comment: If it's a frictionless surface, then the force required approaches zero... just need the tiniest force to start the block moving (since nothing is resisting it) and that's it.

Comment: @Kyle, right! that makes sense! So the above formual should be for the attraction of a magnet to a piece of iron vertically against gravity. I am still wondering though, given the info from the magnet provides website, how am i able to tell what is the maximum weight this magnet can pull (vertically now) at 0.3 M, assuming the magnet is on top. Many thanks

Comment: What's vertical pull? What units do they give you for that? Can you link the website?

Comment: Here's a website giving the data i mentioned about magnets, yet, I cannot relate what is on these websites to the actual case, lets say my question now is as simple as this: What is the maximum mass of iron this magnet (in the link below) can lift against gravity from a distance of 0.3 M.
http://www.first4magnets.com/f201---20-x-10-x-5mm-thick-n42-neodymium-magnet---38kg-pull-x5-b42o-1010-p.asp